# WiX minor upgrade doesn't remove old Shortcut

Tags: wix, wix3

The following steps had been performed:

1. Setup1.msi had been built in VS2005 + WiX 3.0 (.NET Framework 2.0).
2. Version 1.0.0.0 had been installed by Setup1.msi.
3. For the purpose of minor upgrade a Setup2.msi had been built
   (Setup2.msi differs from Setup1.msi ONLY in ProductVersion="1.0.1.0")
4. The following Patch.wxs had been prepared:

   ```
   <Patch
       AllowRemoval="no"
       Classification="Update"
       Comments="..."
       Description="..."
       DisplayName="..."
       Manufacturer="..."
       TargetProductName="...">

   <Media Id="1000" Cabinet="MyPatch.cab">
       <PatchBaseline Id="MyPatch" />
   </Media>

   <PatchFamily 
       Id="MyPatchFamily" 
       Version="1.0.1.0" 
       ProductCode="...THE SAME AS IN Setup1.msi..."            
       Supersede="yes">

       <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Program_EXE" />      
       <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Desktop_Shortcut" />      
       <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ProgramMenu_Shortcut" />
   </PatchFamily>
   </Patch>
   ```
5. Patch.msp had been created with help of candle, light, torch and pyro.exe.
6. The following command had been invoked:

   ```
   msiexec /p Patch.msp REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus
   ```

   As a result, Program.exe was updated and new shortcuts "v. 1.0.1"
   were created.
   However, old Shortcut "v. 1.0.0" remained both on "DesktopFolder" and on
   "ProgramMenuFolder".

   How can I make the Patch remove old Shortcut?
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is not to add version to shortcut name. See [Windows UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511447.aspx#names):

> Avoid putting a version number in a program name unless that is how users normally refer to your program.

---

Otherwise your minor upgrade has to remove the shortcut to the old version and create a new shortcut that points to the new version.

During minor upgrade, the old version does not get uninstalled, that's why the shortcut is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RemoveFile` element within the `Component` one owning the `Shortcut`:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
    <Shortcut Id="..." Name="foobar_1.0.1" ... />
    <RemoveFile Id="..." Name="foobar_1.0.0.lnk" On="install" />
    ...
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

**But**.  There's one problem remained -- when you uninstall you MSP patch, new shortcut (foobar_1.0.1.lnk) is not removed (because the `Shortcut` table is transformed back, I believe).  Therefore, user ends up with two shortcuts.  I do not know how to fix that, therefore I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338093/how-to-remove-desktop-shortcut-with-msi-minor-upgrade).