# How to remove desktop shortcut when MSI minor upgrade is get uninstalled?

Tags: wix, wix3

My customer wants to see some "version number" in file name of the program's desktop shortcut.  For example: "Foobar 10.lnk" or "Foobar 12.lnk".

Therefore, we have the following snippet in one of our .WXS files:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
    <Shortcut Id="...." Name="Foobar_10" ... />
    <RegistryValue ... />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Every time we release a new version, we update that .WXS file.  There's no issues in this scheme while we are producing **major upgrades**, because our major upgrades first uninstall existing product, and then install new version.

But now we have to release a **minor upgrade**.  And put "Foobar 10.1.lnk" file into the "Desktop" directory.  We have, therefore, one MSI file for version 10, another one for version 10.1 and MSP patch to upgrade the product from version 10 to version 10.1.

According to [Changing the Product Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/changing-the-product-code) it's legitimate to add or remove new shortcuts using a minor upgrade:

> The update can add, remove, or modify the ... shortcuts of components that are not shared by two or more features. ... If the update removes resources, it should also update the RemoveFile and RemoveRegistry tables to remove any unused files, registry keys, or shortcuts that have already been installed.

Had we install the MSP file with shortcut snippet from above, we would end up with two shortcuts in the "Desktop" directory: Foobar_10.lnk and Foobar_10.1.lnk due to transformation applied to the `Shortcut` table.  Therefore, according to the article I already mentioned, we have to update the `RemoveFile` table:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
    <Shortcut Id="...." Name="Foobar_10.1" ... />
    <RemoveFile Id="..." Name="Foobar_10.lnk" On="install" />
    <RegistryValue ... />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Now, if one installs that MSP file onto already installed ``Foobar version 10'', he/she gets single .LNK file inside the "Desktop" directory -- Foobar_10.1.lnk.

So far so good.

But if one removes that minor upgrade using the system's "Control panel" (minor upgrade only, therefore, reverting back to ``Foobar version 10''), he/she gets two shortcuts again: Foobar_10.1.lnk "remained" from MSI+MSP, and Foobar_10.lnk created by the `CreateShortcuts` action from the transformed-back `Shortcut` table.

My **main question is**: how I can remove file Foobar_10.1.lnk when the MSP minor upgrade is get uninstalled?  What actions/properties should I "check" to catch such un-installation?

By the way, I tried to get log from un-installation of a minor upgrade, but I failed to uninstall an upgrade using the command line.  For example, this:

```
msiexec -uninstall {valid-patch-guid-here} -package foobar.msi
```

ends up with the maintenance mode for 'foobar.msi'.  Both the following commands:

```
msiexec /I {valid-product-code-guid} MSIPATCHREMOVE={valid-patch-guid}
msiexec -package {valid-product-code-guid} -uninstall {valid-patch-guid}
```

give the same (these commands are from [Uninstalling Patches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstalling-patches)).

I can remove a minor upgrade using "Control panel" only.  Therefore, I can't get un-installation log.  Without it I can't see what happens during that process.  I know it's a bad idea to ask two question at once, but may be anyone knows how to remove a patch using the command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution -- ``[Transitive components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/using-transitive-components)''.  A minor upgrade: a) adds new transitive component for a shortcut (on the "Desktop" and/or in the "Start menu") with condition evaluated to 'true', and b) modifies conditions of existing "shortcut components" to be evaluated to 'false'.

Inspired by "[Minor upgrade fails on removing files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65703349/4635410)" topic on SO.  Thanks christopher-painter@.